# Node.js Async Promises within a forEach Loop inside another then statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have been trying to understand promises nesting with this simple code.

Both functions that I'm calling are async, one giving an entire collection and the other just individual information of each of the elements.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const PirateBay = require ('thepiratebay');
var os = require ('os');
var sys = require('util');
var util = require('util');
var cfg = require('./config/appconf.js');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Torrent = require('./models/torrent.js');
var parseTorrent = require('parse-torrent')

var async = require('async');
function saveResults (results) {
    console.log( "Save Results");
    var cTorrents = [];
    for (var key in results) {
        var t =results[key];
        var torrent = new Torrent()
        torrent.id = t.id;
        torrent.name =  t.name;
        torrent.size = t.size;
        torrent.seeders = t.seeders;
        torrent.leechers = t.leechers;
        torrent.verified = t.verified;
        torrent.uploader = t.uploader;
        torrent.category = t.category.name;
        torrent.description = t.description;
        torrent.subcategory = t.subcategory.name;
        var r = parseTorrent (t.magnetLink);
        torrent.announce = r.announce;
        torrent.hash = r.infoHash;
        cTorrents.push (torrent);
    }
    return cTorrents;
}
PirateBay
    .recentTorrents()
    .then( function(results){
         var lTorrents = saveResults(results);

         async.each (lTorrents,function (t,next){
                await PirateBay
                    .getTorrent(t.id)
                    .then(function (err, doc){
                        console.log(doc.description);
                        t.doc = doc.description;
                        next();
                    });
         },function (err) {
            console.log ("WHNEEEEE");
            console.log(lTorrents);
         });
         console.log(lTorrents);
    })
    .catch (function (err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong? Is there a problem? What is it and what do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the async module, `Promise` should be sufficient. In particular what you might be interested in is [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which takes an array of Promises and resolves when all promises finishes. Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element of `lTorrents` can be mapped into a Promise. Here's an example..

```
PirateBay
        .recentTorrents()
        .then(function(results){
             var lTorrents = saveResults(results);
             return Promise.all(lTorrents.map(function(t) {
                 return PirateBay.getTorrent(t.id)
                     .then(function(doc) {
                         t.doc = doc.description;
                         return t;
                     })
                     .catch(function(err) {
                         // if one request fails, the whole Promise.all() rejects, 
                         // so we can catch ones that fail and do something instead...
                         t.doc = "Unavailable (because getTorrent failed)";
                         return t;
                     });
             }));
        })
        .then(function(lTorrents) {
            // do what you gota do..
        })
```